# react native double tap for submit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to code a handler for email uniqueness. For that reason i coded function that is below. But when i show the user that `"You have to submit unique mail"` message. And then the user typed unique email. It has to tap twice to submit button to navigate other page. What is wrong on that code?

Here is the validation function:

```
  const validateEmailServer = async (mail) => {
    let flag = 0;
    await firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("Users")
      .get()
      .then((querySnapshot) => {
        querySnapshot.forEach((documentSnapshot) => {
          if (documentSnapshot.data().email == mail) {
            setvEmailServer(false);
            flag = 1;
          }

          if (flag == 0) {
            setvEmailServer(true);
          }
        });
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  };
```

OnSubmit handler:

```
const Submit = () => {
    validateEmail(email) ? setvEmail(false) : setvEmail(true);
    validateNickname(nickname) ? setvNickname(false) : setvNickname(true);
    validatePassword(password) ? setvPassword(false) : setvPassword(true);
    validateNicknameServer(nickname);
    validateEmailServer(email);
    if (
      validateEmail(email) &&
      validateNickname(nickname) &&
      validatePassword(password) &&
      vNicknameServer &&
      vEmailServer
    ) {
      navigation.navigate("UserCredential", {
        email: email,
        password: password,
        nickname: nickname,
      });
    }
  };
```

Answer (score -1):

The state of flag will not persist between function calls. You will need to maintain a state for how many clicks there are.

Assuming you are using functional components, it will look something like this:

```
const [buttonClicked, setButtonClicked] = React.useState(0);

// when button is clicked
setButtonClicked(buttonClicked++);

// to check how many times it is clicked
if (buttonClicked === 2) { ... }
```

Comment: But is it a good way for response or side effects?

Comment: @LeoS this is the accepted way to manage local state in React. So it will be fine even in responses.